# What is this symbol (E)?

Tags: fonts, symbols, blackboard

[image: E]

It was in an economics paper and I've been searching for it for 20 minutes with no luck.

I've tried detexify and most normal packages. `amsfonts` [image: E] and `dsfont` [image: E] both don't fit the bill

Comment: It looks very similar to a `\mathds{E}`. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{E}$ 
\end{document}`

Comment: This is a "blackboard bold" E.  Although the particular image is from the `dsfont` package, a version usually considered to be the default is provided by the `amsfonts` package, `\mathbb{E}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I've already tried detexify

Comment: @barbarabeeton I thought `dsfont` was the closest, but the wighted bar is the other side for `dsfont` compared to the one I want

Comment: Go to CTAN and search for "comprehensive".  Go to the directory that holds all the files for that collection.  Look for "raw fonts".  That has font charts for every font covered by the document as a pdf file.  On p.222 is a chart for one of the `tx` (Times) components, and I think you will find a matching "E" there.  Then go to the pdf file for the comprehensive list and look for "alphabets, mathematical".  That list shows only the first few letters of each alphabet, but it identifies the font package and the command to be used.

Comment: By the way, for the images you loaded into the question, you've got `dsfont` and `amsfonts` images reversed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah. Thank you. How would I reproduce that in a Latex document? I don't see any command for it. Sorry if this is a trival question - I'm quite new to Latex.

Comment: do not choose a different font for a single letter, it's simply a double struck E use your document fonts, it's like saying a paper has a g with a closed loop but your font has an open tail, you wouldn't change fonts just for a g. In many papers you will see the author didn't have a double struck font available and simply uses IE (which works better in a serif font)

Comment: Although I agree with @DavidCarlisle that one should stick with the document fonts (if the needed symbol is available), here's the method for adding a new package, for general reference.  Follow the instructions in my previous comment (the page number may change).  In the list of mathematical alphabets, you will find the package name (txfonts); add it in your preamble with `\usepackage`.  Then, for the particular letter, use the command specified for that package -- `\varrmathbb{E}`.  Learn to use the comprehensive symbols list -- it's a treasure!

Comment: @barbarabeeton How would I generalize this? I see on p222 it shows the hex and octal codes for the character, as well as listing `txbmia`. How did you get from `txbmia` to `txfonts` and from there to the command `\varrmathbb{E}` from the raw font tables?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was unclear as to whether the different weights would convey different meanings. This makes sense.

Comment: @user760900 -- The information leading to `txfonts` and `\varmathbb{E}` is found in the main documentation file for the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`) on the page for "mathematical alphabets".  You have to look at both the raw font tables and the documentation.  The exact name in the tables won't usually be matched in the documentation, but in this case, the first two letters, `tx`, are distinct and will match an entry in the alphabets list.  (This becomes easier as you gain familiarity with these resources.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this?

[image]

Observe that the first vertical stroke is thin while the second is thick: That's the same as in the screenshot you posted -- and the reverse of what `\mathds{E}` produces.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[bb=px]{mathalfa} 
\begin{document} 
$\mathbb{E}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer - Just to show the differences between font designer's choices, using some random math fonts (system fonts, so uses `unicode-math` package on xelatex):

[image: blackboard E]

The bb/ds math alphabet tries to emulate writing with the side of the stick of chalk, rather than with the pointy end.

Stay with one font design/package for stylistic consistency, rather than doing mix-and-match with glyphs from different fonts.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfontface\masana{Asana Math}
\setmathfontface\mdejavu{DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mtgdeja{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mpagella{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfontface\mbonum{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfontface\mschola{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfontface\mtermes{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mlatin{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mcambria{Cambria Math}
\setmathfontface\mfira{Fira Math}
\setmathfontface\mfreeserif{FreeSerif}
\setmathfontface\mlibert{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mnoto{Noto Sans Symbols}
\setmathfontface\mqui{Quivira}
\setmathfontface\mstixtwo{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface\mstixgen{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfontface\msymbola{Symbola}
\setmathfontface\mgaramond{\detokenize{Garamond-Math}}
\newcommand\mfsize{\Huge}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\newcommand\themassym{}%

\begin{document}
\section*{Sampling {\mfsize $\themassym $}}

\vspace{24pt}

\begin{tabular}{rccl}
XITS Math & \mfsize $\themassym$ & \mfsize $\mcambria \themassym$ & Cambria Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Asana Math & \mfsize $\masana {\themassym}$ & \mfsize $\mfira \themassym$ & Fira Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mdejavu \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mfreeserif \themassym$ & FreeSerif \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Bonum Math & \mfsize $\mbonum \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mlibert \themassym$ & Libertinus Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mtgdeja \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mnoto \themassym$ & Noto Sans Symbols \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Pagella Math & \mfsize $\mpagella \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mqui \themassym$ & Quivira \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Schola Math & \mfsize $\mschola \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mstixtwo \themassym$ &STIX Two Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Termes Math & \mfsize $\mtermes \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mgaramond \themassym$ & Garamond-Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Latin Modern Math & \mfsize $\mlatin \themassym$ & \mfsize $\msymbola \themassym$ & Symbola \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I was unclear as to whether the different weights would convey different meanings. This makes sense. Thank you for the clarification!