# Help Finding Bold Calligraphic T from New Computer Modern

Tags: unicode-math, newcomputermodern

I am trying to include one specific symbol from the New [Computer Modern font](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern?lang=en). The symbol in question is the regular and bold versions of the calligraphic capital T also called Latin Uppercase Script T per the link. According to the font samples at that link I am looking for the symbols given by `\mscrT` and `\mbfscrT`.

I am able to get the regular version but I can't find the bold. I am trying to print the bold version using `symbf` from the `unicode-math` package.

I would have expected to find a `.otf` file that had both "bold" and "math" in the name but I am not seeing that in the font files at the link above. Instead I can only find:

- `NewCMMath-Book.otf`
- `NewCMMath-Regular.otf`

Does anyone know where I can find the bold version of this symbol? Below is an MWE that I am running in LuaLatex with the font files stored in the same location as `main.tex`.

```latex
% main.tex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf} % just a place holder for MWE to run, not actual main font I am using
\setmathfont[
    Extension = .otf,
    range={\mscrT,\mbfscrT},
    Scale=MatchUppercase
]{NewCMMath-Regular}

\begin{document}

Here is the regular symbol: \(t / \mathcal{T}\).

Here is the bold symbol: \(t / \symbf{\mathcal{T}}\).
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenType Math fonts have the math alphanumeric alphabets in the same font

`\mscrT` is U+1D4AF

and

`\mbfscrT` is U+1D4E3

to print this using `unicode-math` use the commands you mentioned `\mscrT` and `\mbfscrT` or equivalently `\symscr{T}` and `\symbfscr{T}`
or just use the characters directly   and

Answer (score 0):

Longhand script ("running writing") is fading from memory now, and it is rare to find it outside of maths lectures and wedding invitations.

Design in fonts is intended to emulate formal handwriting.

Here is a random sample of  :

[image: calF]

From an Android TeX distro under Termux. Blanks are not on my tablet. Code adapted from [What is this symbol (E)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541485/what-is-this-symbol-e/541542#541542).

Visualising the 1000+ MAS symbol set in Unicode: see [sans serif math font selection using unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262929/sans-serif-math-font-selection-using-unicode-math/605273#605273)